# flutter SizeTransition cause container border radius to not work properly

Tags: flutter, animation

I'm using SizeTransition to animate the width of a container.
This container is supposed to have rounded corners.
The problem is that the rounded corners only work when the sizeTransition is completed. If it is not completed, they remain square (as is shown in the gif below).

[image]

My code:

```
class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DemoPage> createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 5), vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 100),
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 20,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: const Color(0XFFC41D3D).withOpacity(0.5),
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                  ),
                  SizeTransition(
                    axis: Axis.horizontal,
                    sizeFactor: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                        .chain(CurveTween(curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.4)))
                        .animate(_controller),
                        /// the container whose border radius is not working as expected
                    child: Container(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 20,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: const Color(0XFFC41D3D),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
onPressed: () {
          _controller.repeat();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Wrap your stack widget and change its clipBehavior,Try this:

```
Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 100),
              Container( // add this.
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 20,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: const Color(0XFFC41D3D).withOpacity(0.5),
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                    ),
                    SizeTransition(
                      axis: Axis.horizontal,
                      sizeFactor: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
                          .chain(CurveTween(curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.4)))
                          .animate(_controller),

                      /// the container whose border radius is not working as expected
                      child: Container(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0XFFC41D3D),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Worked! Not sure why this happens though.

Comment: you needed to clip the parent of stack instead of rounded the animated one.stack just apply two widget on each other, but by changing the clipBehavior of the stack you can clip all the widget inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap `SizeTransition` with `ClipRRect` which provide more realistic shape.

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  child: SizeTransition(
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this should work, too, but I'm afraid ClipRRect might be a little bit expensive.

Comment: well most widget use `hardEdge`, but ClipRRect use `antiAlias` that can be overridden calling `clipBehavior`

Comment: Also, now I notice top post is using `antiAlias` with Container

Comment: so are they the same？

Comment: I think so,,, while ClipRRect are more specific